# call revert exception in using ether.js

Tags: reactjs, ethers.js, hardhat

i am setting up react with ether.js and smart contract is deployed using hardhat on localhost network. React app is connected to metasmask using

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
```

the contract is written below

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter {
    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        console.log("Deploying a Greeter with greeting:", _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        console.log("Changing greeting from '%s' to '%s'", greeting, _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

i deployed this contract using npx hardhat run script.js.In the react code i am fetching contract object using

```
const erc20=new ethers.Contract(address,obj.abi,signer);
```

and in the useEffect i am trying to call erc20.greet()
which is giving error in console.
**
(in promise) Error: call revert exception (method="greet()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)
**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure these points:

1. **Your Metamask extension is connecting to your hardhat localhost network.**
   When you run your React app in a browser with the Metamask extension installed, make sure that your Metamask is connecting to your hardhat localhost network (by default, it is **localhost:8545**). If Metamask is connecting to a different network, you will get that error.

   *(Note: Because the Metamask extension hides test networks by default, you will need to make it show test networks so that you can see your hardhat localhost network listed.)*
2. **Use the correct contract address.**
   When you start a hardhat local network, hardhat will return a list of accounts like this:

   ```
   WARNING: These accounts, and their private keys, are publicly known. Any funds sent to them on Mainnet or any other live network WILL BE LOST.

   Account #0: 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266 (10000 ETH)
   Private Key: 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80

   Account #1: 0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8 (10000 ETH)
   Private Key: 0x59c6995e998f97a5a0044966f0945389dc9e86dae88c7a8412f4603b6b78690d
   ...
   ```

   When you deployed that smart contract using hardhat on localhost network, hardhat will return something like this:

   ```
   [contract-name] deployed to: [contract-address]
   ```

   Make sure that you use that **[contract-address]** as the value of the **address** argument here:

   ```
   const erc20=new ethers.Contract(address,obj.abi,signer);
   ```

   A **[contract-address]** and an account look quite similar, but they represent two different things. If you use an account instead the **[contract-address]**, you will get the error.